# remove duplicate rows where one column equals a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df like this:

```
d = {'label':['A','B','G','O']
    ,'label2':['C','D','O','Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

  label label2
0   A    C
1   B    D
2   G    O
3   O    Z
```

What i want to do is to get rid of the duplicate rows that have label = label2 (keep only the first)
So i want to get something like this from the above df:

```
  label label2
0   A    C
1   B    D
2   G    O
```

I do this below, but it doesn't do the trick

```
df[~df[['label', 'label2']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
```

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean by  "get rid of the duplicate rows that have label = label2"? It is super unclear from the example , what you want to do.

Comment: So if a row['label'] equals another row['label2'], only keep the first row

Comment: What should happen if you have `O Z` before `G O`

Comment: Same thing. Drop the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) method for Seires:

```
mask = ~df['label'].isin(df['label2'])
df_output = df[mask]
print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
  label label2
0   A    C
1   B    D
2   G    O
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drop` to remove duplicate label between 2 columns:

```
df.drop(df[df['label'].isin(df['label2'])].index, inplace=True)
print(df)

# Output:
  label label2
0     A      C
1     B      D
2     G      O
```